# How to get the parameters in a routed URL from Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, router

If I set: $route['about-us']='sub-directory/article/read/100',then it's OK to use siteurl/about-us.html to browse.
We have below tools to get the original(real)uri:

```
$this->router->directory =>sub-directory
$this->router->class =>article
$this->router->method =>read
```

But how to get the param 100?

Comment: use " segment " function .. Segment function is fetch url value .. " $this->uri->segment(3); " ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to find out what the routing segments are would be to use the URI class, which is part of CodeIgniter's core, so you don't have to load it. First, if you were not using CodeIgniter's URI routing feature, you'd be able to use the segment method, like this:

```
// See: 
// https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::segment

$seg = $this->uri->segment(4);
```

But CodeIgniter's documentation is clear that if you are using URI routing, that you need to use the rsegment method, like this:

```
// See: 
// https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::rsegment

$seg = $this->uri->rsegment(4);
```

For your specific application, you may have to use a different URI segment number, so if 4 doesn't work, then in your case you might try 3.